# How does the rate limiting work on the pagination for twitter v2 api work?

Tags: api, twitter, tweepy

Does it count towards the limit of the same endpoint? So if I was to loop through a list that I receive with a get request with the pagination tokens would each subsequent request count towards the rate limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, each call to the API counts in the rate limit, whether you are using a pagination token or not. You can easily check it by trying to get all the followers of a very famous account.

But please note that, if you are using Tweepy, you don't need to handle the pagination tokens etc. The library contains a `Paginator` class to help you with that (see the documentation [here](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/v2_pagination.html)).